# Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am attempting to upload a file using `Alamofire`. The upload works fine when using a File (`NSUrl`), however, I cant seem to figure out how to use the `NSData` option?

This is what I have as a test:

```
 var url:NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost:8080/bike.jpeg")

 var err: NSError?
 var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)

 Alamofire.upload(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/rest/service/upload/test.png", imageData)
        .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            println(totalBytesWritten)
        }
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
           println(JSON)
 }
```

I am getting a status code 415?

Also, how can I send across additional params in the upload?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I wasn't setting the correct Content-Type:

```
var manager = Manager.sharedInstance
manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"]


let imageData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData.dataWithData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageTest.image, 30));

Alamofire.upload(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/rest/service/upload?attachmentName=file.jpg",  imageData)
        .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            println(totalBytesWritten)
        }
        .responseString { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(JSON)
}
```

Still cant figure out how to send additional parameters along with the upload.

Comment: Use  "multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: image1Data, name: "file", fileName: "myImage.png", mimeType: "image/png")" this is imp otherwise get error "Invalid value around character 0"

Answer (score 81):

Here is a simple function that requires the target upload url, parameters, and imageData and returns the URLRequestConvertible and NSData that Alamofire.upload requires to upload an image with parameters.

```
// this function creates the required URLRequestConvertible and NSData we need to use Alamofire.upload
func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, String>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

    // create url request to send
    var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add image
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData(imageData)

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}
```

Here's an example of how to use it (see CREATE AND SEND REQUEST):

```
// init paramters Dictionary
var parameters = [
    "task": "task",
    "variable1": "var"
]

// add addtionial parameters
parameters["userId"] = "27"
parameters["body"] = "This is the body text."

// example image data
let image = UIImage(named: "177143.jpg")
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)



// CREATE AND SEND REQUEST ----------

let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents("http://example.com/uploadText/", parameters: parameters, imageData: imageData)

Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, urlRequest.1)
    .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
        println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
    }
    .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
        println("REQUEST \(request)")
        println("RESPONSE \(response)")
        println("JSON \(JSON)")
        println("ERROR \(error)")
}
```

And if you need the php file for the target url (with an 'uploads' folder in the same directory):

```
// get picture variables
$file       = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName   = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType   = $_FILES['file']['type'];

// check extension
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
$rootName = reset(explode(".", $fileName));
$extension = end(explode(".", $fileName));

// create new file name
$time = time();
$newName = $rootName.$time.'.'.$extension;

// temporarily save file
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$newName );
if ($moved) $path = "uploads/".$newName;

$body = $_POST['body'];
$userId = $_POST['userId'];


$time = time();
if ($moved) {
    $fullUrl = "http://antiblank.com/testPhotoUpload/".$path;
    $arrayToSend = array('status'=>'success','time'=>$time,'body'=>$body,'userId'=>$userId, "imageURL"=>$fullUrl);
} else {
    $arrayToSend = array('status'=>'FAILED','time'=>$time,'body'=>$body,'userId'=>$userId);
}

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($arrayToSend);
```

Comment: Hi,I already use this method and works well.But in server side they change request content type JSON.after that this method not working.I want to upload data as json...can you please help me out

Comment: almost right,    uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)   in this line  name=\"file\"  ,indeed file is key name that will deal with by server..like paperclip.

Comment: Mines was working before and now im getting NSCocoaErrorDomain code 3840, anyone has solved this issue?

Comment: @antiblank thank you for sharing this code. Could you advise oh how to alter this function so that it can accept either NSData or null for the the picture parameter as users have the option whether or not to upload a picture in my web service call. Could I use anyObject instead of NSData in the definition

Comment: how about PUT request and updating stuff. @antiblank

Comment: how can we do this including headers also?

Comment: @antiblank any method available in Alamofire like AFNetworking.

Comment: I believe this saved me couple days. One thing in my case is that I have to move the for loop for parameters up because my server need the parameters first before it can handle the file.

Comment: Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue in swift 3?

Comment: On swift 3 it should be mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = Alamofire.HTTPMethod.post.rawValue

Comment: How to update this for swift 3 and alamofire4 to create the required URLRequestConvertible?

Comment: How to pass headers @antiblank

Answer (score 76):

Upload Photo / File **with parameters** and **custom headers** via **Swift 3 & 4 and Alamofire 4**

```
// import Alamofire
func uploadWithAlamofire() {
  let image = UIImage(named: "bodrum")!

  // define parameters
  let parameters = [
    "hometown": "yalikavak",
    "living": "istanbul"
  ]

  Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
      multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }

    for (key, value) in parameters {
      multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
    }}, to: "upload_url", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"],
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
          switch encodingResult {
          case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.response { [weak self] response in
              guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
              }
              debugPrint(response)
            }
          case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("error:\(encodingError)")
          }
  })
}
```

via **Swift 2 and Alamofire 3**

```
  // import Alamofire
  func uploadWithAlamofire() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")!

    // define parameters
    let parameters = [
      "hometown": "yalikavak",
      "living": "istanbul"
    ]

    // Begin upload
    Alamofire.upload(.POST, "upload_url",
      // define your headers here
      headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"],
      multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        // import image to request
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
          multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "myImage.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

        // import parameters
        for (key, value) in parameters {
          multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
      }, // you can customise Threshold if you wish. This is the alamofire's default value
      encodingMemoryThreshold: Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
      encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
          upload.responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
          }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
          print(encodingError)
        }
    })
  }
```

Current swift version:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data-to-a-server

Comment: can any body tell me about these below lines
if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
      multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }

    for (key, value) in parameters {
      multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
    }}

Comment: This will not work if `parameters` is `[String:Any]` because `value.data(using: .utf8))!` is not valid for `Any Type`. 
Do you have suggestion how to solve this ?

Comment: what to do when parameters is [String:Any] ? @Chlebta how did you fix this

Answer (score 57):

Here is a Solution using Alamofire 3.0 based on antiblanks answer:

```
 let parameters = [
            "par1": "value",
            "par2": "value2"]    

 let URL = "YOUR_URL.php"

 let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")

 Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, multipartFormData: {
                multipartFormData in

                if let _image = image {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image, 0.5) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    }
                }

                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
                }

            }, encodingCompletion: {
                encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                     upload.responseObject { (response: Response<UploadData, NSError>) -> Void in

                     switch response.result {
                     case .Success:
                         completionHandler?(success: true)
                     case .Failure(let error):
                         completionHandler?(success: false)
                     }

                 }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
        })
```

Comment: How would you go about cancelling this upload? In other answers i see people saying to assing the upload to a var but when i do that the type is inferred as (), thus not allowing methods to be called upon it ? Thanks.

Comment: @SeanLintern88: You may call cancel() on the request-Object. Something like:  upload.cancel(). You can assign the request-Object to a variable and call cancel()

Comment: `case .Success(let upload, _, _)`
`upload` cannot find. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fatihyildizhan `encodingResult` is an `MultipartFormDataEncodingResult` enum. The `.Success Case` has the following parameters:
(`request: Request, streamingFromDisk: Bool, streamFileURL: NSURL?`)
So `upload` is an Request.  Did you add `import Alamofire`?

Comment: How do you keep progress with this?

Comment: @hris.to try something like: `case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                     upload.progress({ (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) -> Void in
                                //HERE YOUR CODE FOR PROGRESSUPDATE
                            }).responseObject { (response: Response<UploadData, NSError>) -> Void in

                 }`

Comment: My parameters dictionary has a value which is itself an array as let params:["studentList":["25","26"]] .  When writing this I am getting error as - "NSObject doesn't have member as dataUsingEncoding" .  What to do in that case?

Comment: Image data is in JPEG representation but MIMEType is wrongly PNG -  "image/**png**"

Comment: multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")                                  Can you please explain the parameters of the appendBodyPart method?

Comment: @EdFunke, it's not working on Alamofire 4.0. Can you give me any link or example that working on 4.0.

Answer (score 10):

Enhancing EdFunke's answer for **Swift 2.2** **Alamofire 3.3.1**

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, urlString, multipartFormData: {
            multipartFormData in
            if let _image = self.profilePic.image {
                if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "user_image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                }
            }
            for (key, value) in userInfo {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
            }
            }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

Multipart upload is scheduled to be included with the next (1.3.0) release of Alamofire.
In the meantime, using the information in this thread, I've made a class that simplifies uploading files and including additional parameters (regular "inputs") in the request along with one or more files.
Without assuming that files are of a particular type or the use of Routers.

FileUploader.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

private struct FileUploadInfo {
  var name:String
  var mimeType:String
  var fileName:String
  var url:NSURL?
  var data:NSData?

  init( name: String, withFileURL url: NSURL, withMimeType mimeType: String? = nil ) {
    self.name = name
    self.url = url
    self.fileName = name
    self.mimeType = "application/octet-stream"
    if mimeType != nil {
      self.mimeType = mimeType!
    }
    if let _name = url.lastPathComponent {
      fileName = _name
    }
    if mimeType == nil, let _extension = url.pathExtension {
      switch _extension.lowercaseString {

      case "jpeg", "jpg":
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"

      case "png":
        self.mimeType = "image/png"

      default:
        self.mimeType = "application/octet-stream"
      }
    }
  }

  init( name: String, withData data: NSData, withMimeType mimeType: String ) {
    self.name = name
    self.data = data
    self.fileName = name
    self.mimeType = mimeType
  }
}

class FileUploader {

  private var parameters = [String:String]()
  private var files = [FileUploadInfo]()
  private var headers = [String:String]()

  func setValue( value: String, forParameter parameter: String ) {
    parameters[parameter] = value
  }

  func setValue( value: String, forHeader header: String ) {
    headers[header] = value
  }

  func addParametersFrom( #map: [String:String] ) {
    for (key,value) in map {
      parameters[key] = value
    }
  }

  func addHeadersFrom( #map: [String:String] ) {
    for (key,value) in map {
      headers[key] = value
    }
  }

  func addFileURL( url: NSURL, withName name: String, withMimeType mimeType:String? = nil ) {
    files.append( FileUploadInfo( name: name, withFileURL: url, withMimeType: mimeType ) )
  }

  func addFileData( data: NSData, withName name: String, withMimeType mimeType:String = "application/octet-stream" ) {
    files.append( FileUploadInfo( name: name, withData: data, withMimeType: mimeType ) )
  }

  func uploadFile( request sourceRequest: NSURLRequest ) -> Request? {
    var request = sourceRequest.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
    let boundary = "FileUploader-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
    request.setValue( "multipart/form-data;boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let data = NSMutableData()

    for (name, value) in headers {
      request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: name)
    }

    // Amazon S3 (probably others) wont take parameters after files, so we put them first        
    for (key, value) in parameters {
      data.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
      data.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }

    for fileUploadInfo in files {
      data.appendData( "\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! )
      data.appendData( "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fileUploadInfo.name)\"; filename=\"\(fileUploadInfo.fileName)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
      data.appendData( "Content-Type: \(fileUploadInfo.mimeType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
      if fileUploadInfo.data != nil {
        data.appendData( fileUploadInfo.data! )
      }
      else if fileUploadInfo.url != nil, let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileUploadInfo.url!) {
        data.appendData( fileData )
      }
      else { // ToDo: report error
        return nil
      }
    }

    data.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    return Alamofire.upload( request, data )
  }

}
```

It would be used like this:

```
// This example uploads a file called example.png found in the app resources

let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("example", withExtension: "png")
let fileUploader = FileUploader()
// we can add multiple files
// this would be equivalent to: <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
fileUploader.addFileURL(fileURL!, withName: "myFile")
// we can add NSData objects directly
let data = UIImage(named: "sample")
fileUploader.addFileData( UIImageJPEGRepresentation(data,0.8), withName: "mySecondFile", withMimeType: "image/jpeg" )
// we can also add multiple aditional parameters
// this would be equivalent to: <input type="hidden" name="folderName" value="sample"/>
fileUploader.setValue( "sample", forParameter: "folderName" )
// put your server URL here
var request = NSMutableURLRequest( URL: NSURL(string: "http://myserver.com/uploadFile" )! )
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
fileUploader.uploadFile(request: request)
```

Check it out or download from this gist: https://gist.github.com/ncerezo/b1991f8dfac01cb162c0

Comment: Hi, is there any way to check out the uploading process success or rather failure in iOS side, in your example case? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Yes, of course. As I mentioned, the uploadFile(request) method returns a Request object, just like the Alamofire.request method, so you can simply chain progress and/or response closures. For example: fileUploader.uploadFile( request: request ).response { (request,response,data,error) in .... }

Answer (score 3):

The code in @antiblank's answer was not working for me. I've made a few changes and it's working now:

```
func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:NSDictionary) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

    // create url request to send
    var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    //let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345"
    let boundaryConstant = "NET-POST-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {

        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        if value is NetData {
            // add image
            var postData = value as NetData


            //uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(postData.filename)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

            // append content disposition
            var filenameClause = " filename=\"\(postData.filename)\""
            let contentDispositionString = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\";\(filenameClause)\r\n"
            let contentDispositionData = contentDispositionString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            uploadData.appendData(contentDispositionData!)


            // append content type
            //uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!) // mark this. 
            let contentTypeString = "Content-Type: \(postData.mimeType.getString())\r\n\r\n"
            let contentTypeData = contentTypeString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            uploadData.appendData(contentTypeData!)
            uploadData.appendData(postData.data)

        }else{
            uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}
```

USE:

```
let docDir:AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let imagePath = docDir + "/myPic.jpg"

var imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: imagePath, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
var parameters = [
            "pic"           :NetData(nsData: imageData!, filename: "customName.jpg"),
            "otherParm"     :"Value"
        ]


    let urlRequest = self.urlRequestWithComponents("http://www.example.com/upload.php", parameters: parameters)
```

The NetData from https://github.com/nghialv/Net/blob/master/Net/NetData.swift

upload.php Code:

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
// PS: custom filed name : pic
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['pic']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
   $array = array ("code" => "1", "message" => "successfully");  
} else {
   $array = array ("code" => "0", "message" => "Possible file upload attack!".$_FILES['pic']['name']); 
}

echo json_encode ( $array );  

?>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you state what change you've made. Was it a simple improve that could be an edit to @antiblank's answer?

Comment: Hi milz ,yes just few change from @antiblank answer,the code is help me very much. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Shorter version based on @antiblank and @VincentYan answers.

## Class

```
class Photo {
    class func upload(image: UIImage, filename: String) -> Request {
        let route = Router.CreatePhoto()
        var request = route.URLRequest.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest
        let boundary = "NET-POST-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary,
                         forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let parameters = NSMutableData()
        for s in ["\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n",
                  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photos[photo]\";" +
                    " filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n",
                  "Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"] {
            parameters.appendData(s.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
        parameters.appendData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1))
        parameters.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n"
                               .dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        return Alamofire.upload(request, parameters)
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
let rep = (asset as ALAsset).defaultRepresentation()
let ref = rep.fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue()
Photo.upload(UIImage(CGImage: ref)!, filename: rep.filename())
    .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
        println(totalBytesWritten)
    }
    .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
        println(JSON)
    }
```

Comment: @TomoMatsumotto When I tried to use your code I am getting error called "Use of unresolved identifier 'Router'", I think Router is an enum you are using here. Could you please update the answer ? Thankz

Comment: @Ankahathara Either create a Router enum or manually create NSURLRequest instead of using Router. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 2):

While there are other answers that advise how to manually construct multipart requests, you might just want to stick with AFNetworking. Even though it's written in Objective-C, you can still use it in your Swift projects (see [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78)). Anyway, the Swift code to submit a multipart request using AFNetworking is as follows:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

manager.POST(uploadURLString, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: { formData in
    formData.appendPartWithFileData(data, name: "image", fileName: "test.png", mimeType: "image/png")
}, success: { operation, responseObject in
    println(responseObject)
}) { operation, error in
    println(error)
}
```

Xcode annoying has problems recognizing this `id<AFMultipartFormData>` parameter, `formData`, so you don't enjoy the typical editor code completion of the `appendPartWithFileData` method or its parameters, but when you compile it, and run it, it works fine.

Comment: This is a good point, but I think that the "manual" piece is somewhat smaller in Alamofire 3. See this answer above (below): http://stackoverflow.com/a/34961720/8047  ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 415 because of missing the **content type** in your request. 
Below is a total soution to image upload on Swift 2 and AlamoFire

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var btnUpload: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func successDataHandler(responseData:String){

    print ("IMAGE UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL    !!!")

}

func failureDataHandler(errorData:String){

    print ("  !!!   IMAGE UPLOAD FAILURE   !!! ")

}

@IBAction func actionUpload(sender: AnyObject) {

    let URL = "http://m8coreapibeta.azurewebsites.net/api/cards/SaveImages"

    let postDataProlife:[String:AnyObject] = ["CardId":(dataCardDetail?.userId)!,"ImageType":1,"ImageData":imageView.image!]

    uplaodImageData(URL, postData: postDataProlife, successHandler: successDataHandler, failureHandler: failureDataHandler)
}

func uplaodImageData(RequestURL: String,postData:[String:AnyObject]?,successHandler: (String) -> (),failureHandler: (String) -> ()) -> () {

    let headerData:[String : String] = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]

    Alamofire.request(.POST,RequestURL, parameters: postData, encoding: .URLEncodedInURL, headers: headerData).responseString{ response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            print(response.response?.statusCode)
            successHandler(response.result.value!)
        case .Failure(let error):
            failureHandler("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are swift and Php Code

Swift code -> Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

```
   class  func upload(jsonObject: AnyObject , files : Array<Any>? = nil  , completionHandler :  CompletionBlock? = nil ,failureHandler : FailureBlock? = nil )
{

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
        { (multipartFormData) in

            if let  filesO = files
            {
                for i in (filesO.enumerated())
                {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "\(i.element)")

                    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1)!

                    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "imgFiles[]" , fileName: "\( NSUUID().uuidString).jpeg" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                  // imgFiles[] give array in Php Side
                  // imgFiles   will give string in PHP String


                }

            }


            for  (key, value)  in jsonObject as! [String : String]
            {

                 multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)

            }}          
    },
                     to:baseURL)
```

**PHP Code to Get Parameters and File**

Here Parameters are  Handle in $_Request

And Files are handle in $_File

Format in  $_File data(Array , Dictionary or String ) will depend on Request in swift side , Here See this line in code

> multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "imgFiles[]" , fileName:
>   "( NSUUID().uuidString).jpeg" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")

in Php side  withName: "imgFiles[]"  gives array of name, format , Type

Eg

> "name":["06748B86-478E-421B-8470-6262755AC149.jpeg","E70269E9-FB54-4BFD-B807-7E418C81540D.jpeg"], "type":["image/jpeg","image/jpeg"],
>   "tmp_name":["/tmp/phpz3UAPq","/tmp/phpCAPExG"], "error":[0,0],
>   "size":[2779495,2067259]}

***PHP Code***

```
 if (isset($_FILES['imgFiles']) and strlen($orderId) > 0) {

        foreach ($_FILES['imgFiles']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {

            $file_name = $key . $_FILES['imgFiles']['name'][$key];
            $file_size = $_FILES['imgFiles']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['imgFiles']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['imgFiles']['type'][$key];
 if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                //move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "user_data/" . $file_name);
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $desired_dir . "/" .
           $file_name);
            } else {         //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir = $desired_dir . "/" . $file_name . time();
                rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

I took antiblank's  answer and wrapped this all up in 1 function with completion handler. Thought it might be useful for someone. It's a bit 'rougher' then antiblank's answer as I'm simply taking a string response from the PHP file (not JSON).

Here's how you call it:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image)

uploadImage("http://www.example.com/image_upload.php", imageData: imageData, subdir: "images", filename: "imageID.png")
    { (req, res, str, err) -> Void in
        // do whatever you want to to for error handling and handeling success
    }
```

Here's the function itself:

```
func uploadImage(urlToPHPFile: String, imageData: NSData, subdir: String, filename: String, completionHandler:(request:NSURLRequest, response:NSURLResponse?, responseString:String?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

    func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, String>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {
        // create url request to send
        var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Method.POST.rawValue
        let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
        mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // create upload data to send
        let uploadData = NSMutableData()

        // add image
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData(imageData)

        // add parameters
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
        return (ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
    }

    let parameters = [
        "subdir" : subdir,
        "filename": filename
    ]
    let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents(urlToPHPFile, parameters, imageData)

    AlamoFire.upload(urlRequest.0, urlRequest.1)
        .responseString(completionHandler: { [weak self] (req, res, str, err) -> Void in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                completionHandler(request: req, response: res, responseString: str, error: err)

            }
        }
    )
}
```

And here is the php file.

```
$subdir = $_POST['subdir'];
$filename = $_POST["filename"];

$targetPath = $subdir.'/'.$filename;

$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetPath );
if ($moved) {
    echo "OK";
}
else {
    echo "Error: file not uploaded";
}
```