# Alamofire uploading progress

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to send a file with the parameters and tracking the progress of uploading. Method

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

don't track progress uploading. Method

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", file: fileURL)
     .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
         println(totalBytesWritten)
     }
     .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
         println(JSON)
     }
```

is not able to set the parameters

is it possible to send a file with the parameters and tracking the progress of uploading?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26153191/1702413

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire/26747857#26747857

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [.uploadProgress](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#upload-progress) instead of **.progress**.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
    activeVidoeCell.uploadRequest = Alamofire.upload(fileData as Data, to: url, method: .put, headers: nil).uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

        print(progress.fractionCompleted)
        activeVidoeCell.downloadButton.setProgress(CGFloat(progress.fractionCompleted), animated: true)

    }).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (result) in

        completionHandler(result)

    })
```