# send a post request including image and json with Alamofire

Tags: alamofire

I find it easy to upload an image with Alamofire.upload(.POST, uploadURL , fileURL) and send a post request including json with Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params,encoding:.JSON)
But how can I send a post request including image and json at the same time? can any one please  help me on this issue? Thank U! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution to your problem that I posted on another question. Instead of copy and pasting everything, just check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire/26747857#26747857). Basically, it provides a simple function which you can use to create the URLRequestConvertible and NSData that Alamofire.upload requires. There's also a quick example and php upload script if you need. Good luck!