# Upload picture using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, curl, afnetworking, alamofire

so my doubt is on how to upload an image using Alamofire, from what researched people uses the solutions here https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/110. However my curl request should look like this:

```
curl -X POST "api.local.app.com:9000/1/media/upload" -F “picture=@filename.png” -H “Authorization: Alpha ahudhasiadoaidjiajdiudaiusdhuiahdu” -v
```

I'm trying to do that this way:

```
Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : "Alpha \(userToken)" ]
        var fileManager = NSFileManager()
        var tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let filename = "tempPicture.png"
        let path = tmpDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
        var error: NSError?
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
        println(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        if(imageData.writeToFile(path,atomically: true)){
            println("Image saved")
        }else{
            println("Image not saved")
        }

        Alamofire.upload(.POST, databaseURL + "/media/upload", NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)!).progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            println( String(totalBytesWritten) + "/" + String(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
            }
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
```

From what I understand this should work however the Alamo returns

> Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value
>   around character 2.) UserInfo=0x7e16d9e0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid
>   value around character 2.}).

Comment: Check this thread out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire

Comment: Also this might be helpful: https://medium.com/@creativewithin/uploading-a-file-in-swift-via-post-multipart-form-data-93dd1001f9e5

Comment: Thx everyone, with the help of every answer I figure it out that the problem was on me when creating the header.

Answer (score -1):

I have already provided a detail answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29224886/1342462). Most likely your server expects the image to be multipart form data encoded which is why it is getting rejected. There are many details provided in that link, along with next steps.

Comment: So them problem was that I was creating the header in the wrong form for my api call. But thx for the help.

Comment: @cnoon Are you the same cnoon from github Alamofire? Aren't you a lead on the Alamofire project? If so thanks for all the work you've put into it.