# Alamofire upload via .POST to PHP. Where is the uploaded file?

Tags: php, swift, post, alamofire

I use the .upload method to upload to a php file on my server and it seems to work (I get a 200 response)

```
upload(.POST, Config.uploadArbeitsauftragURL, urlToFile!)
```

How can I access this file in my PHP file ? 
When I want to use `$_FILE`, I would need a descriptor for the corresponding array-index and I am not able to specify any.

Comment: You may want to take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire

Comment: I do not want to send additional parameters. I simply want one file to upload and access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this same problem today while prototyping something. My slightly hacky solution

*swift*

```
let fileName = "myImage.png"

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let filePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)!

Alamofire.upload(.POST, "http://example.com/upload.php?fileName=\(fileName)", fileURL)
```

*upload.php*

```
// get the file data
$fileData = file_get_contents('php://input');
// sanitize filename
$fileName = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])", '', $_GET["fileName"]);
// save to disk
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```

explanation

It seems Alamofire is sending the file as a octet-stream, so just POSTing the raw file data. We can grab this from php://input but we don't get a filename. So the hacky solution is to just send the filename in the query string.

Remember, this isn't the "right" way. But it's a quick fix for now

Answer (score 0):

I know, but I had the same problem. Everything looked ok but I couldn't access the file data from my server app. By using the method described there (multipart file upload) I was able to upload the file. Additionally, that method allows you to upload more than one file or send other parameters with the request.

Comment: This does provide an answer. Please, note that my first answer was converted automatically to a comment, but I could no comment again, so I needed to add a new answer. But this is connected to my first comment. My first comment points to a solution, disregarded because it talks about sending parameters, but it is actually the solution to the problem. I know it because my problem was the same gutenmorgenuhu has, I didn't need parameters either, but uploading the file as a multipart request was the only way to make the upload work.