# Send POST parameters with MultipartFormData using Alamofire, in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire

I am using Alamofire, very first time. I am using the latest version Alamofire 1.3.1. I want to send one image , one video and some POST parameters in one API call. I am using multipart form data. The mutipart module is working. I am facing a problem to send extra POST parameters`params` . Below is my code. "params" is the dictionary which contains extra parameters? How can I append these POST parameters in the request. Please help

```
        var fullUrl :String = Constants.BASE_URL + "/api/CompleteChallenge"
         var params = [
        "authKey": Constants.AuthKey,
        "idUserChallenge": "16",
        "comment": "",
        "photo": imagePath,
        "video": videoPath,
        "latitude": "1",
        "longitude": "1",
        "location": "india"
    ]

    let imagePathUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath!)
    let videoPathUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath!)

        Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        URLString: fullUrl, // http://httpbin.org/post
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: imagePathUrl!, name: "photo")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: videoPathUrl!, name: "video")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in

                  }
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):

            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found the solution :) finally.

We can append data in the request as multipartformdata.

Below is my code.

```
  Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        URLString: fullUrl, // http://httpbin.org/post
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: imagePathUrl!, name: "photo")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: videoPathUrl!, name: "video")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: Constants.AuthKey.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"authKey")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\(16)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"idUserChallenge")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "comment".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"comment")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"\(0.00)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"latitude")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"\(0.00)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"longitude")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"India".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"location")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in


                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):

            }
        }
    )
```

**EDIT 1:** For those who are trying to send an array instead of float, int or string, They can convert their array or any kind of data-structure in Json String, pass this JSON string as a normal string. And parse this json string at backend to get original array

Comment: If I have an array as a parameter then.

Comment: You will have to convert array in string. One can not send array in parameters.

Comment: Okay actually my backend pHP is wanting me to send array as parameter as that API works for android. So if I send it encoding in string so I also need to have modifications in my backend pHP also....right.

Comment: Can I print multipartFormData so that I know what i am going to send to server ?

Comment: can anyone update it for swift 3 and Alamofire 4 please. I am having trouble converting parameter to type data  when passing parameters to the append function.

Comment: @Ankush please can you convert your answer into Alamofire 4.0 into swift 3?

Comment: @Ankush hii bro need help from this

Comment: @Ankush How can i pass array into this ? As per my requirement it should not convert into string i need to pass array.

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya I edited my answer. You can try that approach

Answer (score 41):

In Alamofire 4 it is important to add the body data **before** you add the file data!

```
let parameters = [String: String]()
[...]
self.manager.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "user", fileName: "user.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    },
    to: path,
    [...]
)
```

Comment: how about audio file? - i try to send a audio file in this form : multipartFormData.append(audioLocalPath, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "application/octet-stream") but occur this error : multipartEncodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.MultipartEncodingFailureReason.bodyPartFileNotReachableWithError(file:///var/mobile/Containers/....... /Documents/item.mp3, NSUnderlyingError=0x16049100 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})) - where is problem? -bad request or bad audio path?

Comment: `No such file or directory` looks like a bad file path

Comment: yes! - i know it's bad path but im try get path with way : ` let localPath = audioURL.appendingPathComponent(audioName!)` , and it work for image but not for audios

Comment: Hello Alexander , i am started swift 3.0 and now i am using Almofire 4. I tried to upload image but its not working for me. Even i am not getting response from server.

Comment: Does the server receive the request with or without data?

Comment: request.FILES shows nothing in django, but the body has the image info!:(

Comment: This gave me an error: "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'data'". I just used this instead: "multipartFormData.append("\\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)"

Comment: "In Alamofire 4 it is important to add the body data before you add the file data"

This line meant a lot to me. I was stuck for 2 days just because I was adding image first and then body and server was returning 400. Thanks

But it didn't happened in my earlier apps using alamofire 4. This was the first time and was totally weird. Can anyone explain why?

+1

Answer (score 21):

This is how i solve my problem

```
let parameters = [
            "station_id" :        "1000",
            "title":      "Murat Akdeniz",
            "body":        "xxxxxx"]

let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1.png")!,1)



    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
        //    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "user", fileName: "user.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }

        MultipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1.png")!, 1)!, withName: "photos[1]", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        MultipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1.png")!, 1)!, withName: "photos[2]", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")


    }, to: "http://platform.twitone.com/station/add-feedback") { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value)
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError): break
            print(encodingError)
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3 / Alamofire 4.0** *(Addendum to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957717/4573247))*

To append to `multipartFormData` in Swift 3 / Alamofire 4.0, use the following method of [`MultipartFormData`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/MultipartFormData.swift):

```
public func append(_ data: Data, withName name: String) { /* ... */ }
```

And, to convert `String` to `Data`, the `data(using:)` method of `String`. E.g.,

```
multipartFormData.append("comment".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "comment")
```

Comment: thanks. do you have any example with a `URLRequestConvertible` parameter?

Comment: I have to append Int data so what to do? Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 8):

**Alamofire 5 and above**

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(Data("one".utf8), withName: "one")
    multipartFormData.append(Data("two".utf8), withName: "two")
    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "photo.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
}, 
to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseDecodable(of: MultipartResponse.self) { response in
        debugPrint(response)
}
```

documentation link: [multipart upload](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data-to-a-server)

Comment: What is MultipartResponse ?

Comment: This is the latest solution, some answers are really outdated. The current major Alamofire is 5. Should use this over other solutions.

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 4.2 / Alamofire 4.7.3**

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipart in
    multipart.append(fileData, withName: "payload", fileName: "someFile.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    multipart.append("comment".data(using: .utf8)!, withName :"comment")
}, to: "endPointURL", method: .post, headers: nil) { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.response { answer in
            print("statusCode: \(answer.response?.statusCode)")
        }
        upload.uploadProgress { progress in
            //call progress callback here if you need it
        }
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print("multipart upload encodingError: \(encodingError)")
    }
}
```

Also you could take a look at [CodyFire lib](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/CodyFire) it makes API calls easier using Codable for everything.
Example for Multipart call using CodyFire

```
//Declare your multipart payload model
struct MyPayload: MultipartPayload {
    var attachment: Attachment //or you could use just Data instead
    var comment: String
}

// Prepare payload for request
let imageAttachment = Attachment(data: UIImage(named: "cat")!.jpeg(.high)!,
                                 fileName: "cat.jpg",
                                 mimeType: .jpg)
let payload = MyPayload(attachment: imageAttachment, comment: "Some text")

//Send request easily
APIRequest("endpoint", payload: payload)
    .method(.post)
    .desiredStatus(.created) //201 CREATED
    .onError { error in
        switch error.code {
        case .notFound: print("Not found")
        default: print("Another error: " + error.description)
        }
    }.onSuccess { result in
        print("here is your decoded result")
    }
//Btw normally it should be wrapped into an extension
//so it should look even easier API.some.upload(payload).onError{}.onSuccess{}
```

You could take a look at all the examples in [lib's readme](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/CodyFire)

Answer (score 5):

***Swift 5***, update @Ankush's *`Alamofire`* Code to

```
     var fullUrl = "http://httpbin.org/post" // for example

           Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append( imagePathUrl! , withName: "photo")
                multipartFormData.append( videoPathUrl!,  withName: "video")
                multipartFormData.append(Constants.AuthKey.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "authKey")
                multipartFormData.append("16".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "idUserChallenge")
                multipartFormData.append("111".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "authKey")
                multipartFormData.append("comment".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "comment")
                multipartFormData.append("0.00".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "latitude")
                multipartFormData.append("0.00".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "longitude")
                multipartFormData.append("India".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "location")

            }, to: fullUrl, method: .post) { (encodingResult) in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(request: let upload, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):
                    upload.responseJSON { (response) in   // do sth     }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    ()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

As in Swift 3.x for upload image with parameter we can use below alamofire upload method-

```
static func uploadImageData(inputUrl:String,parameters:[String:Any],imageName: String,imageFile : UIImage,completion:@escaping(_:Any)->Void) {

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile , 0.5)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: imageName, fileName: "swift_file\(arc4random_uniform(100)).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

            for key in parameters.keys{
                let name = String(key)
                if let val = parameters[name!] as? String{
                    multipartFormData.append(val.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: name!)
                }
            }
        }, to:inputUrl)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        completion(JSON)
                    }else{
                        completion(nilValue)
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                completion(nilValue)
            }

        }

    }
```

> Note: Additionally if our parameter is array of key-pairs then we can
>   use

```
 var arrayOfKeyPairs = [[String:Any]]()
 let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayOfKeyPairs, options: [.prettyPrinted])
 let jsonPresentation = String(data: json!, encoding: .utf8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, since Multipart Form Data is intended to be used for binary ( and not for text) data transmission, I believe it's bad practice to send data in encoded to String over it.

Another disadvantage is impossibility to send more complex parameters like JSON.

That said, a better option would be to send all data in binary form, that is as Data.

Say I need to send this data

```
let name = "Arthur"
let userIDs = [1,2,3]
let usedAge = 20
```

...alongside with user's picture:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "img")!
```

For that I would convert that text data to JSON and then to binary alongside with image:

```
//Convert image to binary
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

//Convert text data to binary
let dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["name": name, "userIDs": userIDs, "usedAge": usedAge]
userData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
```

And then, finally send it via Multipart Form Data request:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiFoormData) in
        multiFoormData.append(userData, withName: "user")
        multiFoormData.append(data, withName: "picture", mimeType: "image/png")
    }, to: url) { (encodingResult) in
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for alamofire 4 use this ..

```
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append(fileUrl, withName: "video")
       //fileUrl is your file path in iOS device and withName is parameter name

        }, to:"http://to_your_url_path")
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _ , _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                    print("uploding")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                   print("done")

                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("failed")
                print(encodingError)

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one more way of doing it

```
 if let parameters = route.parameters {

                    for (key, value) in parameters {
                         if value is String {
                            if let temp = value as? String {
                                multipartFormData.append(temp.description.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                            }
                        }
                        else if value is NSArray {
                            if let temp = value as? [Double]{
                                multipartFormData.append(temp.description.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                            }
                            else if let temp = value as? [Int]{
                                multipartFormData.append(temp.description.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                            }
                            else if let temp = value as? [String]{
                                multipartFormData.append(temp.description.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                            }
                        }
                        else if CFGetTypeID(value as CFTypeRef) == CFNumberGetTypeID() {
                            if let temp = value as? Int {
                                multipartFormData.append(temp.description.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                            }
                        }
                        else if CFGetTypeID(value as CFTypeRef) == CFBooleanGetTypeID(){
                            if let temp = value as? Bool {
                                multipartFormData.append(temp.description.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if let items: [MultipartData] = route.multipartData{
                    for item in items {
                        if let value = item.value{
                            multipartFormData.append(value, withName: item.key, fileName: item.fileName, mimeType: item.mimeType)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alamofire 5 with Array params**

The issue for me was that my params could be any type. Converting to them to strings and then getting the data encoding worked for most, but I kept running into issues with arrays. For arrays you have to encode each element with a key denoting its index. This is how I ended up encoding my params so it would be dynamic for any type:

```
            let image = UIImage(named: "your image") // Change me
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!
            let imageKey = "image_key" // Change me
            let urlString = "https://yourserver.com/yourendpoint/" // Change me
            let params: [String: Any]? = [:] // Change me. Your POST params here
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                // Change me. Your headers here.
            ]
            AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
                for (key, value) in (params ?? [:]) {
                    if let arrayObj = value as? [Any] {
                        for index in 0..<arrayObj.count {
                            multiPart.append("\(arrayObj[index])".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "\(key)[\(index)]")
                        }
                    } else {
                        multiPart.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                    }
                }
                multiPart.append(imageData, withName: imageKey, fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }, to: urlString, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    if let dictionary = response.value as? [String:Any] {
                        print("success", dictionary)
                    } else {
                        print("error")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("error", error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
```

Also note that you have to append the image *after* appending all your params

Answer (score -1):

```
func funcationname()
{

    var parameters = [String:String]()
    let apiToken = "Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "vAuthToken")!)"
    let headers = ["Vauthtoken":apiToken]
    let mobile = "\(ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.getUserData(key: "mobile"))"
    parameters = ["first_name":First_name,"last_name":last_name,"email":Email,"mobile_no":mobile]

    print(parameters)
    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.showSVProgressHUD(text: "Loading...")
    let URL1 = ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.API(Join: "user/update_profile")
    let url = URL(string: URL1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        multipartFormData.append(self.imageData_pf_pic, withName: "profile_image", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")


        for (key, value) in parameters {

            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

    }, with: urlRequest) { (encodingResult) in

        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    let status = (JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! Int
                    let sts = Int(status)
                    if sts == 200
                    {
                        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()
                        let UserData = ((JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary)
                        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.setUserData(data: UserData)


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()

                        let ErrorDic:NSDictionary = (JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "message") as! NSDictionary

                        let Errormobile_no = ErrorDic.value(forKey: "mobile_no") as? String
                        let Erroremail = ErrorDic.value(forKey: "email") as? String

                        if Errormobile_no?.count == nil
                        {}
                        else
                        {
                            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUDWithError(error: Errormobile_no!)
                        }
                        if Erroremail?.count == nil
                        {}
                        else
                        {
                            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUDWithError(error: Erroremail!)
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()
            print(encodingError)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to explain how this answers the question.

Comment: it is user when developer want to pass image data  and other information using alamofire

Answer (score -1):

```
 func savePostWithImage(title: String, content: String, image: UIImage){
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "title":    title,
        "content":  content
    ]
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/proyecto/crud/save.php") else { return }
    
    guard let imgData = image.pngData() else { return }
    
    let imageId = UUID().uuidString
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
            MultipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "Image", fileName: "\(imageId).png", mimeType: "image/png")
            
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                MultipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }
            
        }, to: url, method: .post).uploadProgress { Progress in
            print(Progress.fractionCompleted * 100)
        }.response { [self] response in
            createdPostAlertMessage = successCreatingPostMessage
            showReponseAlert = true
        }
    }
    
}
```