# How to Upload iPhone Videos to server using Alamofire in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http, alamofire

When I record video on iPhone, I would like to press **use video button** to upload video and post other parameters to server using **Alamofire** in iOS **Swift**. How I can do it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST parameters with MultipartFormData using Alamofire, in iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949118/send-post-parameters-with-multipartformdata-using-alamofire-in-ios-swift)

Comment: Have you tried it? did you work on some code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        Alamofire.upload(.POST, API_URL, multipartFormData: { (formData:MultipartFormData) in
        formData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath), name: name)
        }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                    print(totalBytesRead)
            }
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                   //uploaded
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            //Something went wrong!
            if DEBUG_MODE {
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    })
```