# alamofire upload images with json parameters

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am new to **swift** 
I want to upload **images** (from 1 to 4 - depending on user) and a **video** file(if user prefer) to my server and also send other parameters when uploading (like text and etc.) 
in android I was using retrofit which allowed me to use @**partmap** for uploading my nested Json objects. 
now in iOS I am using Alamofire but I couldn't
 find this functionality to send json with multipart
how can I should do this?
 I don't want base 64 image I already tried this
and my text content are nested 
clearly I want to send json parameters when uploading data
for example:

```
image 1 = image
post->content = "some text"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST parameters with MultipartFormData using Alamofire, in iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949118/send-post-parameters-with-multipartformdata-using-alamofire-in-ios-swift)

Comment: @SaqibOmer my parameters are nested so i don't  know how to use mentioned solution. can you help?

Comment: First of all you need to do a multipart request. You can add parameters in your request. You can create nested parameters using a NSDictionary. Also if you can edit your question add some code, may be  I can answer it.

Comment: @SaqibOmer i am using Alamofire as networking library and it provides upload method for uploading multipart data but in this method i can only send text data as key-value pairs but my data are nested and server side separates this data

Comment: Check My answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentiontioned in comments you need a multipart request.

```
// Image file which you want to upload.
guard let image = UIImage(named: "YourImage") else { return }


                let imgRep : NSBitmapImageRep = image.representations.first as! NSBitmapImageRep

                let imgData : Data = imgRep.representation(using: .PNG, properties: [:])!


                let cameraFileName    = "some_random_name_img.png"

                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: cameraFileName, isDirectory: true)
                do {

                    try imgData.write(to: fileUrl, options: NSData.WritingOptions.atomic)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // Stop Camera Session if you are capturing image from camera
                        self.cameraSession.stopRunning()

                        let someParam   = ""
                        let someParam2  = ""


                        let date = Date()
                        let dateString = "\(date)"



                        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

                        // Add parameters in request 

         multipartFormData.append(cameraFileName.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "name")

         multipartFormData.append(dateString.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "startDatetime")

         multipartFormData.append(someParam.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "userId")

         multipartFormData.append(someParam2.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "phoneServiceId")

         multipartFormData.append(fileUrl, withName: "file")

                        }, to:"Your_Api_Url.com") // POST Url
                        { (result) in
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let upload, _ , _):

                                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                                    print("uploding")
                                })

                                upload.responseJSON { response in
                                    print(response)
                                    print("done")






                                }

                            case .failure(let encodingError):
                                print("failed")
                                print(encodingError)

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
                }
```

Comment: i converted my json to string then added it as multi part data to alamofire request and it worked well thanks for your attention