# Swift Upload text of Text Field to a txt file in the server

Tags: swift, server, textfield

I'm trying to upload the text in the Text Field to a txt file in a server. The idea is to add this text to the last line of the txt file, say the txt file is called "file1.txt". How to do this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iFlN.png)

I could only find the tutorial teaching how to upload the image to the server but not pure string to an existing file in the server.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can divide elements of miltupart/form-data using boundary https://github.com/newfivefour/BlogPosts/blob/master/swift-form-data-multipart-upload-URLRequest.md or you alamofire library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949118/send-post-parameters-with-multipartformdata-using-alamofire-in-ios-swift

Comment: sorry...i couldn't follow it, could you please elaborate more?