# How to perform a post with Alamofire (swift) to get a security token as return value

Tags: swift, post, alamofire, amadeus

I want to request a token via cURL using Swift Alamofire. However, I could not figure out so far how to pass on the right parameters in the right order to make it work.

The description given by Amadeus is the following:

[image]

```
 let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

let params = [
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
]


Alamofire.request("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).authenticate(user: "API", password: "API").responseJSON { response in debugPrint(response)

    let result = response.result.value
    print(result)
}
```

The expected result is to get JSON file in return including the token to make API requests. any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637437/alamofire-with-d/53637821#53637821)  since you have a `cURL`. Also, does it work if you put the curl into a Terminal ?

Comment: The encoding `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` isn't JSON, so use `encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make use of usefull debug tools of Alamofire since you have a `cURL` sample.

Let's break your current code:

```
let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

let params = ["grant_type": "client_credentials"]

let request = Alamofire.request("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
                                method: .post,
                                parameters: params,
                                encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                                headers: headers).authenticate(user: "API", password: "API")
print(request.debugDescription)
request.responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
    let result = response.result.value
    print(result)
}
```

Output:

```
$>curl -v \
-X POST \
-u API:API \
-H "Accept-Language: fr-US;q=1.0, en;q=0.9, fr-FR;q=0.8" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
-H "User-Agent: iOSTest/1.0 (nt.iOSTest; build:1; iOS 12.2.0) Alamofire/4.8.1" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "{\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}" \
"https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token"
```

Let's go piece by piece:
We should forget about Accept-Encoding, User-Agent & Accept-Language headers. I'll skip them later.

We see that the `-d` (data into httpBody) is wrong.

Let's change that: `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` to `encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)`. Plus it makes sense since in the content type we said it was url encoded.

We get then:

```
$>-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Seems better.

We see the `-u API:API \` which correspond to `.authenticate(user: "API", password: "API")`. We might want to remove it if the server doesn't manage authentification like that and put it into the params instead. 
So now, let's change the params:

```
let params = ["grant_type": "client_credentials",
              "client_id" : "APIKey",
              "client_secret" : "APISecret"]
```

We get:

```
$>-d "client_id=APIKey&client_secret=APISecret&grant_type=client_credentials" \
```

It should work then.

The order is not the same, but server shouldn't care about it. It should be a key/access not an index/access.

So final:

```
let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

let params = ["grant_type": "client_credentials",
              "client_id" : "APIKey",
              "client_secret" : "APISecret"]

let request = Alamofire.request("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
                                method: .post,
                                parameters: params,
                                encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody),
                                headers: headers)
print(request.debugDescription)
request.responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
    let result = response.result.value
    print(result)
}
```

Output (with skipped headers):

```
$ curl -v \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "client_id=APIKey&client_secret=APISecret&grant_type=client_credentials" \
"https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token"
```

Comment: first of all: Your solution turned out to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for that. I edited your answer and added the API call. Unfortunately it returns unknown. Any suggestions why this might be the case?

Comment: BTW security token stores the value from the .post method

Comment: Don't try to edit my answers with another question. Instead create a new question.

Comment: Sorry. Created a new question

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that the parameters should include `grant_type:client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}`. Your parameters are missing the client ID and client secret. Make sure to include those by doing something like this:

```swift
let params = [
    "grant_type": "client_credentials&client_id=CLIENTIDHERE&client_secret=CLIENTSECRETHERE"
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately amadeus server responds with    error = "invalid_request";
    "error_description" = "Only client_id, client_secret and grant_type parameters are allowed in the body";
    title = "Invalid parameters";

Answer (score 0):

The string that has to be passed as body is:

```swift
let params = [
    "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENTIDHERE&client_secret=CLIENTSECRETHERE"
]
```

I don't know much about Swift but I guess you could do:

```swift
let params = [
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    "client_id" : "Your API Key"
    "client_secret" : "Your API Secret"
]
```