# sending token in header for key Authorization but always getting 401 for get api swift

Tags: swift, header, authorization, alamofire

I am sending this header:

```
[
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Accept-Encoding": "br",
  "Authorization": "token 6cb39474cc2ae0ea1d1ca34bebe03ac89fdcc8e4"
]
```

The token is valid and working in Postman, but not in iOS.

Comment: Check if you need any 'Subscription-Key'

Comment: You are using Alamofire since it's tagged with Alamofire, no? Here is a tip to compare by doing "curl" equivalent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637437/alamofire-with-d/53637821#53637821 since in Postman, we can convert into curl too: https://blog.getpostman.com/2016/02/03/curl-and-postman-work-wonderfully-together/ and compare. No? If no Alamofire, show your code, and the Postman equivalent Swift generated.

Comment: i have checked with different API Manager and it worked.
so i think issue with Alamofire.