# Issue while sending array of dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I am creating array of dictionaries and then passing that in `paramDictionary` and sending to server but I get **responseStatus code 422**. I am using Alamofire 5.

Here is the structure of param which I have to send and it successfully working on postman but in app it is always fails

```
{"check_in": [{"check_in_at":"2020-02-26 03:23:44", "gps_coordinates":"3.1697998046875,101.61672197976593"}, 
{"check_in_at":"2020-02-26 03:23:45","gps_coordinates":"3.1697998046875,101.61672197976593"}]}
```

Here is my code

```
func postCheckInApi(viewController: UIViewController,
                          completion:@escaping (_ result:SuccessErrorData)->(),
                          errorHandler:@escaping (_ result:Error,_ statusCode:Int?)->()//error handler
) {

    let url = KCheckin
    let geoArr = Constant.getSearchLocationHistory() ?? [GeoTaggingEntity]()
    var arr = [[String: String]]()

    for i in geoArr{
        let dict: [String : String] = ["gps_coordinates" : i.gps_coordinates ?? "", "check_in_at" : i.check_in_at]
        arr.append(dict)
    }
    let parameterDictionary = ["check_in": arr] as [String : Any]
    print(parameterDictionary)
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": Constant.getBearerToken() ?? ""
    ]

    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameterDictionary, headers: headers).responseData { response in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let data):
            do{
                let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(SuccessErrorData.self, from: data)
                print("Success")
                completion(jsonData)
            }
            catch{
                //viewController.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see check_in_at key in your dictionary, while adding it to array. Please add that key also

Comment: can you please show the response of  `print(parameterDictionary)`

Comment: @Gyanendra here it is "let dict: [String : String] = ["gps_coordinates" : i.gps_coordinates ?? "", "check_in_at" : i.check_in_at]"

Comment: @Manoj. here it is
 ["check_in": [["gps_coordinates": "3.170011520385742,101.61671682755713", "check_in_at": "2020-02-26 07:02:44"], ["check_in_at": "2020-02-26 07:02:45", "gps_coordinates": "3.170011520385742,101.61671682755713"]]]

Comment: Are you able to do your request in POSTMAN? If so, you can ask POSTMAN to get you a Swift code (bad code, but you can find differences), OR you can use POSTMAN to generate `curl` code that Alamofire can translate too. For curl comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637437/alamofire-with-d/53637821#53637821

Answer (score 1):

You can not add `Array` as parameter object to your `paramDictionary`. You need to covert your `Array` to `json string` and then add it to you `paramDictionary`.

For that use below `Collection` extension to convert your `Array` to `Json String`

```
extension Collection {
    func json() -> String? {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: []) else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
}
```

**How To Use**

```
let jsonStr = yourArray.json()
```

add this jsonStr to your `paramDictionary`

Comment: let parameterDictionary = ["check_in": arr.json()]// as [String : Any]
print(parameterDictionary as Any)
["check_in": Optional("[{\"check_in_at\":\"2020-02-26 13:59:47\",\"gps_coordinates\":\"3.1390933990478516,101.6148388824553\"},{\"gps_coordinates\":\"3.1390933990478516,101.6148388824553\",\"check_in_at\":\"2020-02-26 13:59:47\"}]")]
Got Error: The check in must be an array