# How to send [String:Any] dictionary in multipart API?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am trying to send multipart image data using `Alamofire` with [String:Any] parameters ,i am only able to to post `[String:String]` parameters only

For `[String:String]` is doing like https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440371/4466607

but now i have to post like :
 [ PayLoad ] and i have to send Image with `image` key which, i am already doing  .

In postman it is working fine 
[image]

**Question** : 
How can i post image with Dictionary type `[String:Any]` in Swift
Please help

Answer (score 0):

> If your value is Any type then check this may be it helps you.

```
for (key, value) in params {
  let paramsData:Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
  formData.append(paramsData, withName: key)
}
```

Comment: i am already doing this , i need to post payload of type `[String,Any]` along with my image

Comment: let updateInfo: [String:Any] = ["email":usernameText]
  
for (key, value) in updateInfo {
            multipartFormData.append(key.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: value as! String)
        } 
-try this code

Comment: No , you are appending wrong with data , `withName : key`  i know how to append but not working this way , please try then post

Answer (score 0):

**Rough solution:**
If you insist on put Image data into a dictionary, you could convert image data to Base64 code, and then put Base64 string in the dictionary. You will submit a big JSON to the server. I don't think it's a good solution.

**Better solution:**
Another WebApi to submit images data,  and that API will return uploaded images URL like `https://www.example.com/image1234.jpg`, or just return image id like "1234" which can be embedded to a URL lately. Finally, you submit the JSON data with image URL or id like `{"image":"https://www.example.com/image1234.jpg"}` or `{"image":1234}`.

Comment: No i don't want to put image inside Dictionary