# Upload image with alamofire

Tags: swift, upload, alamofire

I'm trying to upload an image to server with Alamofire but my code doesn't work. This is my code:

```
var parameters = ["image": "1.jpg"]
    let image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents("http://tranthanhphongcntt.esy.es/task_manager/IOSFileUpload/", parameters: parameters, imageData: imageData)
    Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
        .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
        }
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            println("REQUEST \(request)")
            println("RESPONSE \(response)")
            println("JSON \(JSON)")
            println("ERROR \(error)")
    }
```

and this is urlRequestWithComponents methos:

```
func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, String>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

    // create url request to send
    var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add image
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData(imageData)

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}
```

and this is what I get in console:

> REQUEST  { URL: http://tranthanhphongcntt.esy.es/task_manager/IOSFileUpload/ }
>   RESPONSE Optional( { URL: http://tranthanhphongcntt.esy.es/task_manager/IOSFileUpload/ } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
>       Connection = close;
>       "Content-Length" = 345;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html";
>       Date = "Tue, 25 Aug 2015 10:52:01 GMT";
>       "Last-Modified" = "Mon, 24 Aug 2015 03:54:55 GMT";
>       Server = Apache;
>   } })
>   JSON nil
>   ERROR Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7f8c68c1c130 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})

my PHP content:

```js
<? php
echo $_FILES['image']['name'].
'<br/>';


//ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
//ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
//ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);


$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

try {
  //throw exception if can't move the file
  if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    throw new Exception('Could not move file');
  }

  echo "The file ".basename($_FILES['image']['name']).
  " has been uploaded";
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('File did not upload: '.$e - > getMessage());
} ?>
```

My code followed this suggestion: [Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire/27014372#27014372)
.Please help me, thanks

Comment: Did you found the solution ?

Comment: i think it's a best practice to add validate in from of responseJSON
`.validate().responseJSON`

Comment: You can find the solution via **Alamofire 3+** with **multi parameters** and **custom headers**.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34961720/2125010

Answer (score 6):

While [Rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) Answer is correct, here's the *Swift 2.0* version, with **upload progress** update.

Just Copy and Paste the following code, change the upload URL, and add in your parameters. Should work like a charm.

PS: [MRProgress](https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress) is an Awesome Library for progress update!

```
    let apiToken = "ABCDE"
    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        "http://sample.com/api/upload",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "yourParamName", fileName: "imageFileName.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: apiToken.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"api_token")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: otherBodyParamValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"otherBodyParamName")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
                    print("Uploading Avatar \(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        /**
                        *  Update UI Thread about the progress
                        */
                    })
                }
                upload.responseJSON { (JSON) in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        //Show Alert in UI
                        print("Avatar uploaded");
                    })
                }

            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                //Show Alert in UI
                print("Avatar uploaded");
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error is telling you that the response is not valid JSON. You're calling `responseJSON`, indicating that you're expecting JSON response, but your server code isn't generating JSON. So there are two solutions:

1. I'd suggest changing your PHP code to generate JSON responses.

   For example, if successful:

   ```
   echo json_encode(array("success"    => true,
                          "filename"   => basename($_FILES['image']['name']));
   ```

   or, if not successful, perhaps:

   ```
   echo json_encode(array("success"    => false,
                          "error_code" => 42,
                          "error_msg"  => 'File did not upload: '.$e - > getMessage());
   ```

   Clearly, you have to remove the extraneous `echo` lines in the PHP if you're going to return JSON, but hopefully this illustrates the pattern. But this will generate a response that you can parse with Alamofire's `responseJSON` (or use `NSJSONSerialization`).
2. Alternatively, you could change the Alamofire code to not expect JSON (e.g. call `response` rather than `responseJSON`), but then parsing the responses becomes far more difficult.

As a minor, unrelated issue, I'd personally advise not building that request manually, but rather let Alamofire do that for you. Here's an [example from the README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-multipartformdata):

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")
    },
    to: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

This is for Swift 3 and Alamofire 4. See revision history for this question for prior versions.

Comment: Rob could you please help me with my issue it is also associated with alomofire upload request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977486/how-to-upload-zip-data-with-alamofire

Comment: Just use the `.uploadProgress` and/or `.downloadProgress` as shown in the "Upload Progress" section of README's [Uploading Data to a Server](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-data-to-a-server).

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 2 AlamoFire total Solution for image upload to REST API**

AlamoFire contain load of simplified solution. Alamofire.request method contains several simplified overload which can use to upload in simple manner. By using Alamofire.request( method developer can get rid of encoding overhead.

Please check my solution below.

The solution was Tested on SWIFT 2.0

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var btnUpload: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func successDataHandler(responseData:String){

        print ("IMAGE UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL    !!!")

    }

    func failureDataHandler(errorData:String){

        print ("  !!!   IMAGE UPLOAD FAILURE   !!! ")

    }

    @IBAction func actionUpload(sender: AnyObject) {

        let URL = "http://m8coreapibeta.azurewebsites.net/api/cards/SaveImages"

        let postDataProlife:[String:AnyObject] = ["CardId":(dataCardDetail?.userId)!,"ImageType":1,"ImageData":imageView.image!]

        uplaodImageData(URL, postData: postDataProlife, successHandler: successDataHandler, failureHandler: failureDataHandler)
    }

    func uplaodImageData(RequestURL: String,postData:[String:AnyObject]?,successHandler: (String) -> (),failureHandler: (String) -> ()) -> () {

        let headerData:[String : String] = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]

        Alamofire.request(.POST,RequestURL, parameters: postData, encoding: .URLEncodedInURL, headers: headerData).responseString{ response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print(response.response?.statusCode)
                successHandler(response.result.value!)
            case .Failure(let error):
                failureHandler("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: It doesn't work: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (UIImage)'

Answer (score 0):

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
      "userid":user.userID!
    ]

    print("the uploadData - \(parameters)")

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(deviceImage.image!, 1)

    let url = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string:"your URL here")!, method: .post, headers: nil)

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
      multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "file_name", fileName: "abc.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
      for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
      }
    }, with: url, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
            switch result {

            case .success(let upload, _, _):

              upload.responseJSON { response in

                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                  PrepareUIElements.showAlertAndPerformSegue(sender: self, message: "Uploaded Successfully", identifier: "ShowHome")
                } else {
                  print("whatever you want")
                }
              }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
              PrepareUIElements.showAlert(sender: self, message: "Unable to Upload")
              print(encodingError)
            }

    })
```