# Swift 3 How To Send A Multipart Post Request With Vapor

Tags: swift, xcode, post, vapor

I'm using vapor to host images for my app.I have the following code to recieve the image and print it.

```
drop.post("saveArt") { request in
if let contentType = request.headers["Content-Type"], contentType.contains("image/png"), let bytes = request.body.bytes {
    let image = NSImage(data: Data(bytes))
    print(image)
    return JSON(["Testawesome":"awesome123"])
}
return JSON(["test":"123"])
}
```

How can I send a multipart request using just swift?.Here is the current post request code i'm using.

```
 let tiffData = imagetosend?.tiffRepresentation
 let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffData!)
 let image_data = imageRep?.representation(using: .JPEG, properties: [:])
 print("Hi")

 let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/getArt")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"


//define the multipart request type

request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


let body = NSMutableData()

let mimetype = "image/png"

//define the data post parameter




body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append(image_data!)
body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)


request.httpBody = body as Data



let session = URLSession.shared


let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    (
    data, response, error) in

    guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print(dataString)

}

task.resume()
```

Comment: You want to send this data from Vapor, OSX or iOS app?

Comment: You can use Alamofire as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32204889/3803872

Comment: Answer didn't help I will post the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using this alamofire method.

```
Alamofire.request("YOUR URL", method: .post, parameters: parm, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: { json in
        // If you want to return json.
        print(json)
    })
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know how you put that code using Alamofire on a Linux machine. I added Alamofire version 4 to my Vapor project but could not build the project on Vapor.cloud because of a missing module `SystemConfiguration` in NetworkReachabilityManager.swift. (The code was working on my Mac of course)