# How can I pass body parameters along with file in multipart file upload using Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, alamofire

I am working on multi part file upload with Alamofire Library in Swift. I need to pass some parameters along with the file. The following is the body I need to pass to the server:

```
{
  "eventId":7,
  "eventImageList":[
    { "contentType":"png", "imageName":"test", "imagePath":"" }
    ,
    { "contentType":"png", "imageName":"test2", "imagePath":"" }
  ]
}
```

I have tried similar to this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "sampleImage")

Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, multipartFormData: {
    multipartFormData in
        if let _image = image {
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image, 0.5) {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }
        }
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key as! String)
        }

    }, encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in

        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                     print("jsonResponse ==== ", response)
                case .Failure(let error):
                     print("error ==== ", error)
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
})
```

I need to pass this array:

```
[
  { "contentType":"png", "imageName":"test", "imagePath":"" }
  ,
  { "contentType":"png", "imageName":"test2", "imagePath":"" }
]
```

but when I decode it like below, the app crashes.

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire)

Comment: its not the duplicate i need to pass an Array of data as parameter but when i try this multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key as! String) app is crashing

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had this problem when I try to upload an image (Alamofire) with parameters like that(dictionary within dictionary).

Here's an example:

```
let params:[String:Any] = ["client" : ["name" : "Some", "email" : "some@some.com"]]
for (key, value) in (params["client"] as! [String:Any]) {
     multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "client[\(key)]")
 }
```

The trick is in this part:

```
withName: "client[\(key)]"
```

Comment: not working, can we print the multipartFormData to check if the values we are sending?

Answer (score 0):

change your code from

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key as! String)
}
```

to this :

```
for (key, value) in parameters {
    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.