# Upload file with params using Alamofire

Tags: swift, http-post, alamofire

I am trying to upload file with params, but it fails.
Is there something wrong with the code below?

**refer**
[Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire)

Swift

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, url, multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) -> Void in
            let fd = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.8)!
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: fd, name: "image", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            for (k, v) in params {
                let d = v.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: d, name: k)
            }
            }) { (encodingResult) -> Void in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        if response.result.isSuccess {
                            print("success")
                        } else {
                            print("fail")
                        }
                    }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    self.view.makeToastCenter(message: "fail \(encodingError)")
                }
```

Comment: @Shripada I got "success", but file not uploaded. And no log on server too.

Comment: I know reason now. Because server do not return a json data , just a string

Comment: Good, so problem solved?:-) @aitian16 ?

Comment: @Shripada Yes. Thank you for comment.