# Swift Upload Image to Server

Tags: php, ios, swift

I want to Upload a Image to my Webserver through JSON Encoding in Swift and tried some suggestion from other Threads and Comments. I think the best solution is the following, but know i get an other error-message
Here is my Code, including the Image Picker:

```
    @IBAction func goToLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            myImageView.image = pickedImage
        }

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func uploadImage(sender: AnyObject) {

        uploadWithAlamofire();


      }


       func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, String>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

            // create url request to send


var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
        let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
        mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



        // create upload data to send
        let uploadData = NSMutableData()

        // add image
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.jpg\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData(imageData)

        // add parameters
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



        // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
        return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
    }


    // import Alamofire
    func uploadWithAlamofire() {

        // init paramters Dictionary
        var parameters = [
            "task": "task",
            "variable1": "var"
        ]

        // add addtionial parameters
        parameters["userId"] = "27"
        parameters["body"] = "This is the body text."

        // example image data
        let image = myImageView.image;
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)



        // CREATE AND SEND REQUEST ----------

        let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents("http://myWebserverdomain.com/project/uploadPhoto.php", parameters: parameters, imageData: imageData!)

        Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
            .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
                println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
            }
            .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
                println("REQUEST \(request)")
                println("RESPONSE \(response)")
                println("JSON \(JSON)")
                println("ERROR \(error)")
            }    
    }
```

Here the PHP-File:

```
   <?php
// get picture variables
$file       = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName   = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType   = $_FILES['file']['type'];

// check extension
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
$rootName = reset(explode(".", $fileName));
$extension = end(explode(".", $fileName));

// create new file name
$time = time();
$newName = $rootName.$time.'.'.$extension;

// temporarily save file
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "img/".$newName );
if ($moved) $path = "img/".$newName;

$body = $_POST['body'];
$userId = $_POST['userId'];


$time = time();
if ($moved) {
    $fullUrl = "http://myWebserverDomain.com/project/".$path;
    $arrayToSend = array('status'=>'success','time'=>$time,'body'=>$body,'userId'=>$userId, "imageURL"=>$fullUrl);
} else {
    $arrayToSend = array('status'=>'FAILED','time'=>$time,'body'=>$body,'userId'=>$userId);
}

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($arrayToSend);
?>
```

EDIT:

I tried the Answer from "antiblank" from here : "[Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire)" with Alamofire.

But know i get an error which reads as follows:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTD5p.png)

I hope someone knows the answer to this, because i searched the last 5 hours for a solution.

Thank you all!

Comment: Alamofire may save your time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire

Comment: I've tried Alamofire but i didn't work for me, or I make another mistake ..

Comment: Can you post yout alamofire code? may be simpler to help

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Hello. Please don't add the solution to a question. A question should remain a question. You can post the solution yourself *as an answer* if you want, it's perfectly fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've solved it, so everbody from this( [Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire)) thread, i hope this would help you.

Just delete :

```
 .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            println("REQUEST \(request)")
            println("RESPONSE \(response)")
            println("JSON \(JSON)")
            println("ERROR \(error)")
```

You don't get a response from your server but the code itself works.
I don't know why but Swift 2.0 don't except this.

I hope this helps.

Greets!