# Why I cannot send multipartFormData with .POST parameters in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, multipartform-data, alamofire

When I'm trying to send this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            URL,
            parameters: parameters,
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
```

it prints me the next error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

I want to send my image file with the next parameters:

```
{
    "user": {
        "firstName": "ABC",
        "email": null,
        "birthDate": "1988-01-03",
        "books": [{
            "id": 1
         }, {
            "id": 2
         }]
    },
    "locale": "en",
    "sign": "It's me", 
}
```

because of this structure, I cannot append it to multipart and I do not need send my parameters as a body of multipart, but as a parameters.

Is there any solutions for it?

Comment: You can try this current solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34961720/2125010

Comment: No, there he used `multipartFormData.appendBodyPart` but I want as `parameter` to send @fatihyildizhan

Comment: by the way, what is your excuse? I don't know the difference between them.

Comment: Also there is this one, it's old but working. May be the same thing, I'm not sure.
https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient

Comment: @fatihyildizhan okay, but how can I append an array to my multipart? other parameters are okay, but array is diffucult

Comment: I am sending my array data as a class with POST request then uploading image separately with another request. If you can change your backend service, I can give more detail.

Comment: no, I know how to send it separately. I need to send it in one request @fatihyildizhan