# How to send multipart response of jpegs

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipart, mjpeg, gcdwebserver

Having an embedded HTTP Server in an iOS application, How can I respond to an HTTP Request with a multipart message? 
I'd like to asynchronously send JPEGs in a multipart response (MJPEG).

I've tried doing so using [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer), if it's not supported by it, any working alternative would be fine as long as it can also work on iOS.

Comment: Maybe this implementation of Alamofire can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire

Alamofire docs can be found here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCDWebServer has no built-in API to create multipart messages. You would need to write such code and output a `NSData` object, which then you wrap into a `GCDWebServerDataResponse` that you return to the HTTP client.

Comment: The way HTTP works, you can only send one response per request.

Comment: That's not technically accurate, you can send the response as chunks at different times (such that it suspend the "first" chunk from closing the request) -> for the same request. Motion-JPEG takes advantage of it, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it's not directly supported by GCDWebServer, and for creating this useful library :) would be nice if a solution comes up though.

Comment: No, no, it's technically correct. Just because you send a response in multiple chunks, doesn't make it multiple responses :)

Comment: Note that GCDWebServer does support chunk content encoding for requests and responses, which `GCDWebServerStreamedResponse` leverages.

Comment: Heh, well, yeah, that's what I'm trying to achieve :D. So is `GCDWebServerStreamedResponse` capable of emitting multiple chunks of data at different times (possibly an indeterminate amount of chunks)? I'm basically forwarding jpegs using an MPEG chunked stream to a browser's `video` tag. obviously I can't guess when the stream ends, or how many jpegs I have to forward, since It has to be like "real time" video.
Is there any documentation on how to do something similar using `GCDWebServerStreamedResponse`?

Comment: There's no documentation for this, you're going to be on your own. Note that if you don't transmit any data for 30-60s, it's likely the browser will close the connection thinking it's stalled.