# How to send a jpeg file as a parameter in a POST request using AlamoFire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to make a server request using Alamofire.
I need to send a file as a parameter.

```
    var parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    parameters["PAYLOAD"] = payloadString // String
    parameters["FINGERPRINT"] = deviceUniqueIdString // String
```

I have a UIImage that I convert to NSData using UIImageJPEGRepresentation()

```
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myUIImage, 1.0)
    parameters["IMAGE_FILE"] = imageData
```

Then, I use Alamofire to send the request:

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, apiURL, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

    }
```

This request works when I only send the payload and fingerprint parameters, but when I include the "IMAGE_FILE" parameter, the server returns error.

How should I send the UIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Fujia response, I wanted to add an example. This is the method I have been using recently for posting png files:

```
func WasperEntrepriseImageUploadCall(method: Alamofire.Method, imageData: NSData, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, headers: [String: String]?, urlToPost: String, 
    progressionHandler: (bytesWritten: Int, totalBytesWritten: Int, totalBytesExpected: Int) -> (), 
    completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<AnyObject,NSError>, NSData?) -> ()){

    Alamofire.upload(
        method, urlToPost, headers: headers,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "doesntmatter", mimeType: "image/png")

            if let params = parameters{
                for (key, value) in params {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
                }
            }
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
                    progressionHandler(bytesWritten: Int(bytesWritten), totalBytesWritten: Int(totalBytesWritten), totalBytesExpected: Int(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
                }
                upload.response { response in
                                          }.validate()
                    .responseJSON { response in

                        if let resp = response.response{
                            print(resp.statusCode)
                            print(response.result.value)   // result of response serialization                          
                        }
                        completionHandler(response.request,response.response,response.result, response.data)
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Not the best solution, but it should give you a head start. Requires both SwiftyJSON and Alamofire 3.0 I believe. Gives you a completion handler for progress which can be useful. You should be able to find a more detailed answer here : [Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Alamofire.upload(_:multipartFormData:encodingMemoryThreshold:encodingCompletion:)` instead of `Alamofire.request`. You can add your parameters (including both strings and data) in the mutipart closure.